# PowerBuilder 9 connectivity to Oracle Database Server 11.2.0.2

Tags: oracle11g, powerbuilder

Current desktop application is developed using PowerBuilder version 9 with Oracle 9.2 as a back end. Now I need to migrate the back end Oracle to 11.2.0.2. From Googling I found PowerBuilder 9 is no longer supported. Is it possible to connect to Oracle 11.2.0.2 with PB 9? Kindly let me know if I can migrate the same application to higher version of PB like PB 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [this response from Terry Dykstra](http://groups.google.com/group/sybase.public.powerbuilder.database/browse_thread/thread/68d950231f491190/5c4ccd399c41d919?q=%28%22powerbuilder%209%22%20OR%20%22pb%209%22%20OR%20pb9%29%20oracle%2011g%20group%3asybase.public.powerbuilder.%2a#5c4ccd399c41d919) you'll see your options under PB9 are:

> the O90 driver, ODBC, OLEDB or JDBC

As for migrating to a higher version, migrating to higher versions of PB are typically comparatively small efforts (but no guarantees), assuming you have all the source code.

You mention upgrading to PB11. Keep in mind that PB11 also is no longer supported. Sybase (now an SAP company) typically supports current and previous major versions (with some overlap), so right now that means 12.5 and 12.0.

Good luck,

(another) Terry

Comment: If I connect using odbc and do I need to change source code? So connecting oracle 11g via oracle 9i will not cause unhandled exception and code rewrite ?

Comment: ODBC: Don't know, but my best guess is that it depends on how you've written your SQL. 9i Driver: I wouldn't expect any code changes, but I'd also expect you'll be limited in the 11g features you can take advantage of. If you want the Oracle upgrade to be of any front-end benefit, you'll probably have to upgrade PB to a version that will take advantage of it.